# Gridlines on Excel multi page report

Tags: excel, printing

I have made a report in Excel 2019 with header and footer along with grid lines on specific portion of the page, leaving some cells without grid lines. This is a multi page report. When I print the report, I can see the grid lines on the 1st page correctly on the desired portion, but on subsequent pages the grid lines are completely missing.

If I use the option of "print gridlines" in Page setup dialog box, the grid lines do appear in all pages but it covers the entire page with grid lines which I do not want.

Is there any setting in Excel which I can use?

Thanks